# XamarinStore has stopped

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I'm having some trouble running the Xamarin Store demo app from Visual Studio. When I'm attempting to run the Xamarin demo application from Visual Studio 2013 on a virtual android device and I'm either on the receiving end of a "xamaring store has stopped error" or the application breaks on ln 24 of XamarinStore.MainActivity:

`SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);`

The console log contents:

`Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External] An unhandled exception occured.`

`08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono    ( 2258): Unable to find seq points for method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger:Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception)'. 08-17 17:40:02.041 F/        ( 2258): * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/163212a9/source/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:5241, conditionsp' not met 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): Stacktrace: 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): ================================================================= 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): used by your application. 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): ================================================================= 08-17 17:40:02.041 E/mono-rt ( 2258): Step request failed: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown. The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

The installation of xamarin is a clean one. I'm running the 4.4W SDK - API Level 20.

Comment: Is it Xamarin Store or a InAppBilling-demo you are trying to run? To use a test application with inapp-purchase functionality you cannot run this on a virtual device.

Comment: It is the Xamarin Store demo application

Comment: Maybe you have already read some of this, but ill just post this link in case you haven't seen it. Hope it helps. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16097/xamarin-store-app-sample-does-not-run

Comment: The link suggests using API level 19 instead of 20. Unfortunately that fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved by reverting to an earlier version of the Android SDK.